# Send mail with embeded image without a library in php?

Tags: php, html-email, mailing

I'm sending mail with the `mail()` function of php. I embed image using base64 encoding inside the html code, but in gmail for example it doesn't show.
I read that a best way to do that is to use `cid` in the html code and attaching the image but I find only codes using phpmailer which I would like to avoid but the question is, is it possible with the php `mail` function or is there some simple classes to simplify the process ?

```
    $message = $html_mail;
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'To: '. $to . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: My website <'.$admin_mail.'>' . "\r\n";
    $response = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Question, is the image publicly accessible (by url) or you wish to attach it?

Comment: are you sure that gmail is the problem? are you able to see your image using any other email client?

Answer (score 0):

Instead to using base64_encode image you should use html image tag with src path of your server, so it will download from your server.

```
<img src="http://www.yourserver.com/myimages/image1.jpg">
```

As your mail is having text/html header image will automatically parse via email client.

Comment: You said "should use", what if his requirement prevents that?  I'm assuming it does since he specifically asked about sending embedded images.

Comment: Joey is true I need embeded image because gmail doesn't show remote image (in my case maybe because I'm testing on another server with which mails go to spam), but embeded images with cid src work but I need to use phpmailer.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the "Original Source" in Gmail, you may find that gmail is editing the html to remove the image.  idk if it does that or not though.  I would try copying the html from the email in gmail and putting it in an html file and see if it loads in a browser correctly.  Then you'll know for sure if gmail is messing it up or if it's a bug in another place.

FYI, sending html emails that work in all email clients can be a huge PAIN.  The best guide I know of is this - https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/ . SitePoint also sells a book about it that is the gold standard IMO.

Good luck!

Comment: I know it's a pain to send a well formatted mail but my problem is just for the images and yes gmail modify the content and doesn't show base64 embeded images. Thanks for the link.